# IF() function not working on Numbers fetched with VLOOKUP()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have fetched some values with VLOOKUP from another sheet into column B and column E.
Both Column B and E shall match and they are as you can see. 
But when I run the function IF(B# = E#,TRUE,FALSE), it is only working on text and failing on numbers in column "I"

Can anyone guide me with this please ?

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the `IF` not working for numbers. That works just fine. It's probably within the values you return. You better return to your `VLOOKUP` data and see how that is formatted. It might just actually turn out to be numbers formatted like text with trailing spaces (or other invisible chars), you wouldn't be the first one =)

Comment: Also, since your vlookup data is in a sheet called "paste" it think the above is not far off =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the `IF` formula will work fine on numbers. You won't be the first to have pasted values that look like numbers but are formatted as text and though might end up with trailing spaces or other unseen characters.

You can edit your formula to account for that but its more recommendable to go to your vlookup data and see if you can rework that data.

Good luck =)

Answer (score 1):

JvdV was right, I initially pasted values in the 'paste' sheet from where the VLOOKUP is fetching the data to this sheet. I took a look at 'paste' sheet and there were correction tags on numbers with "Numbers stored as text", I had to use 
=VALUE(VLOOKUP(XYZ)) to fetch numbers and the IF started working well.